# Developing and testing AngularJS apps (and apps in general)

Tags: angularjs

I have an app I am building, like most I have built in the last few years, with a clean separation: REST API on the back-end, Angular (before that Backbone, before that just jQuery) on the front-end.

When first testing, it is easy to stub the REST API; when developing, I can do things like a static file server (like angular-seed's `./scripts/web-server`) and put in place files. But at a certain point, I really need to develop and test against the real REST API.

How do people build against and launch in a case of a separated app like this? In the past, I had a `./dev` node script which would set all sorts of test/dev database variables, then `require('../../server-dev-dir/app.js')` but it seems sort of heavy. Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Same issue for testing: the app really needs to be tested against a true REST API, at a certain point, stubs and mocks only help so much.

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS, you make all of your HTTP requests using the `$http` service. It's not your job to test `$http`. That's the job of AngularJS team. All you care about is this:

*does your back-end or 3rd party (API) back-end receive the requests that `$http` is sending **as configured** by your AngularJS code?*

To that end, AngularJS provides the [`$httpBackend`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend) mock. When `angular-mocks.js` is loaded in your tests, `$http` will send HTTP requests to it. You can train `$httpBackend` on how to respond to any URL.

You can also make assertions on what requests `$httpBackend` received and what data it received with those requests.

Comment: nice to see you again. I see what you are saying, my issue is that sometimes mocks aren't enough. When you build a Web app with a REST API with, say, 50 different paths, and POST to one affects GET from another, you are almost rebuilding your whole backend API in a mock! Wouldn't your prefer to use your real server-side app running locally? Or is there some simpler way to mock it?

Comment: @deitch, Yeah, I think you're right. There can be a lot of work involved in mocking your backend, but since responses are hard-coded in `$httpBackend`, it's not quite as bad as rebuilding the entire back-end from scratch. Not sure if that would work, but you could try not including `angular-mocks.js`. Perhaps that'll get your `$http` to send real requests to your server. But then you'll have to write asynchronous tests, which is not so bad in my opinion.

Comment: I don't mind async tests. I usually use mocha, but either way, async isn't so bad. But the UI exercises so much of the REST API - actually, all of it - that I found myself recreating it, might as well just launch it.

Comment: I used mocha and got used to it first with Node.js. Then when I starting doing the front-end with AngularJS, I tried to use it there too. Things didn't work out so well. There are subtle syntax differences between Jasmine and mocha that can make things confusing. Since the AngularJS team is so invested in Jasmine, all the tips, tricks, and tutorials are made for it, so I had to eventually switch back to Jasmine and the journey got a lot less bumpy that way. Just a heads up!

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. I will keep an eye out. My REST API tests ae all mocha, but I will watch for those gotchas in Web UI. Can you point me to some examples?

Comment: Here's a [popular article](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html) on how to test AngularJS using mocha as the framework.